# Finding a second-order differential equation given a first-order differential

Tags: differential-equations

If I have a differential equation, say, $${dy\over dx}=x+y$$ or in Mathematica:

```
y'[x]==x+y[x]
```

how can I find $d^2y\over dx^2$? From what I can tell, the `D` function only takes an "anonymous" $f(x)$ that can't reference itself in its definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility is to tell [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue) what to solve for:

```
DSolveValue[y'[x]==x+y[x], y''[x], x]
```

> E^x C[1]

in agreement with halirutan's answer.

Comment: Thank you! I always assumed the second argument to DSolve had to be in the form `a[b]` to tell it what function to to solve for, I had no idea it could solve for different kinds of expressions.

Comment: Hehe.. this is nice. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *find* the second derivative, then you could solve the differential equation and use the `y[x]` result with `D`:

```
DSolveValue[y'[x] == x + y[x], y, x][x]
D[%, {x, 2}]
(* E^x C[1] *)
```